# Can't compile source code on mac

Tags: macos, xcode, open-source, gcc

I already have xcode installed on OSX Yosemite. I have also run it and accepted terms and conditions.

I can also do `gcc --version` and I see

```
Configured with: --prefix=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
Apple LLVM version 7.0.0 (clang-700.1.76)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin14.5.0
Thread model: posix
```

Now if I do

```
wget http://apache.mirrors.pair.com//httpd/httpd-2.4.17.tar.bz2
brew install pcre
tar zxvf httpd-2.4.17.tar.bz2
cd httpd-2.4.17
./configure
```

The error I get is

```
Configure:
configure: Configuring Apache Portable Runtime Utility library...
configure:
checking for APR-util... yes
checking for gcc... /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/OSX10.10.xctoolchain/usr/bin/cc
checking whether the C compiler works... no
configure: error: in `/Users/abhi/Downloads/httpd-2.4.17':
configure: error: C compiler cannot create executables
See `config.log' for more details
```

Why can't the C compiler create executable? I showed you that the C compiler is installed correctly on my machine.

Comment: For current OS X gcc is not the C compiler - you have not shown the C compiler is installed correctly - The C compiler is clang

Comment: @Mark but `gcc` is symlinked to `clang` by default, and in straightforward case the invocation is `gcc`-compatible. @KnowsNotMuch have you indeed  ``See `config.log' for more details`` as the autoconf suggested?

Comment: @Saran it is not linked to clang - could you point to some documentation that says so

Comment: Have you installed the command line tools?

Comment: @Mike OK my bad it's not _symlinked_. However it does just run a copy of clang: here's my shell output `oxygen:~ saran$ gcc clang: error: no input files`. Also if I recall correctly, the command `gcc` wouldn't even run without the command line tools installed.

Comment: yes command line tools are installed

Comment: Can you put the config.log into a pastebin and link to it in your question?  The answer is in there somewhere.

Answer (score 9):

You need to convince configure that there are more c compilers than gcc.
Try:

```
export CC=clang
```

Answer (score 2):

In general, having Xcode installed isn't enough to get some open source projects to compile.

The actual error you are seeing is probably listed in `config.log` since the test it makes is failing on OS X. It's hard to guess if that's because it doesn't like clang/llvm which is what your "`gcc`" binary actually is.

Some boilerplate things to try:

```
xcode-select --install
```

That should issue an error like "xcode-select: error: command line tools are already installed, use "Software Update" to install updates" when you have all the tools actually installed. If you don't have the tools and include files installed, you should get a prompt to install the tools and have to possibly type an admin user/password.

Next, you could dig into the actual specific error log or you could try getting a gcc compiler instead of using Apple's llvm.

```
brew install gcc
```

That would get a gnu `gcc-5` installed in the `/usr/local/bin` path and if that's used over Apple's `/usr/bin/gcc` you might not have the build error in the first place.

Comment: I tried both your suggestions and this is what i got `Last login: Sat Nov 21 22:58:10 on ttys000
MacBook-Pro:~$ xcode-select --install
xcode-select: error: command line tools are already installed, use "Software Update" to install updates
MacBook-Pro:~$ brew install gcc
Warning: gcc-5.2.0 already installed
MacBook-Pro:~$`

Answer (score 2):

Start Xcode, select 'Preferences', then 'Locations'. You'll notice a dropdown control at 'Command Line Tools'. Select the newest version, close the dialog window, then call brew again.

Answer (score 1):

After doing

```
xcode-select --install
```

run

```
open /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Packages/macOS_SDK_headers_for_macOS_10.14.pkg
```

This worked for me.