# Apple clang++ error: wchar.h:119: fatal error: 'wchar.h' file not found #include_next <wchar.h>

Tags: macos, xcode, homebrew

[MacOS 10.14.5, Xcode 10.2, CLI Tools, brew clang-9/clang++]

For some reason I am no longer able to build a simple hello world program using `clang++ main.cpp`.  Instead, I am getting an error:

```
clang++ main.cpp
In file included from main.cpp:9:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include/c++/v1/iostream:38:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include/c++/v1/ios:215:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include/c++/v1/iosfwd:90:
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include/c++/v1/wchar.h:119:15: fatal error: 'wchar.h' file not found
#include_next <wchar.h>
              ^~~~~~~~~
```

I installed the homebrew's `llvm` yesterday because Apple's version does not support the -fopenmp flag correctly.  I'm wondering if installing the 2nd version of clang may have changed something I didn't notice and now I can't figure out.

Two things strike me here;
1. why can't `wchar.h` find itself in the same directory that it is already at? (Note that it fails on the `#include_next`, which is inside the header file it supposedly can't find.)
2. Why is Xcode using `XcodeDefault.xctoolchain` showing instead of `MacOSX10.14.sdk`.

I've read countless posts about how to fix this using `xcode-select` but unfortunately, it doesn't.

Nonetheless, I have tried

```
sudo xcode-select /Applications/Xcode.app
```

and reinstalled my commandline tools, but to no avail.

```
xcrun --show-sdk-path
```

returns the correct path:

```
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.14.sdk
```

One answer suggested setting an environment variable in my bash profile, but since I didn't need it in the past, I don't like that option.

Whilst `clang++ main.cpp` doesn't work, I am able to build using any of the following:

```
xcrun clang++ main.cpp
/usr/local/opt/llvm/bin/clang++ main.cpp
g++ main.cpp  (This execute's Apple's version)
/usr/local/bin/g++-9 main.cpp
I can also build/run from within an Xcode (GUI) project (CLI Tool)
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: `sudo xcode-select -switch /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer` Run this https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/216573/cant-compile-source-code-on-mac/367057#367057 Are you using Cmake GUI?

Comment: Unfortunately, that didn't work.  And no, I'm not using the cmake gui here.  I'm just trying to use `clang` to compile/link the hello world program.  The real reason for wanting this to work is that `pip2 install gdbgui` fails due to a clang error, and I don't know how to tell `pip2` to use a different compiler, not that I really should have to.

Comment: Why should I use cmake?  `clang++ main.cpp` should produce `a.out`.  That's all I want.

Comment: Same question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46342411/wchar-h-file-not-found

Comment: I already have that symlink in my Xcode install, so that answer has not fixed my issue. Since I already have Command Line Tools installed and not using any make system, none of the other answers help.

Comment: The reason for the error is because MacOS Mojave does not have a `/usr/include` folder and `clang++` default sysroot is `/`.  So it looks like I have to specify sysroot everytime I want to invoke Apple's `clang++` or `clang` but not for `gcc` and `g++`.  The other compilers are correctly configured to work with their default sysroots.